# What are sets, matrices, …etc?

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, vectors

I am writing a CS research paper where I'm using sets, matrices, and vectors to solve a particular problem. I have two sets, $R$ and $T$, that will be used throughout the entire solution, and a couple of other sets and matrices that won't be used much, so, I wanted to define $R$ and $T$ before writing the approach. Here is what I said:

$\dots\text{we will define some basic structures that will be used}\dots$

And I think $\text{“basic structures”}$ is wrong, so my question is what do I call (how do I refer to) sets, matrices, vectors, ...etc? How do I say what I want to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, “structures” is a bad option. I think that “entities” is a much better choice.

Comment: I agree. IMO another good choice could be 'objects'

Comment: Thanks, based on your answer and this page [What is a mathematical entity?](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~udr/papers/inaugural-slides/sld038.htm) I'm gonna go with “entities”.

Answer (score 1):

"We begin by establishing  some notation  that will be used below. $R=\dots$,  $S=\dots$"